# How to perform bulk update on AppEngine Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The following code is not working. Does anyone know how I might get it to work?

```
Query q = new Query("Product");
    Iterable<Entity> entities = datastore.prepare(q).asIterable();
    for (Entity entity : datastore.prepare(q).asIterable()) {
        entity.setProperty(“sale”, false);
    }
    datastore.put(entities);
```

`sale` is a completely new field that I am adding to the entity kind. So it does not exist yet.

**UPDATE**

I fixed it as below but the code is still not working

```
Query q = new Query("Product");
    Iterable<Entity> entities = datastore.prepare(q).asIterable();
    for (Entity entity : entities) {
        entity.setProperty(“sale”, false);
    }
    datastore.put(entities);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in your code. You never update `entities`. It should be:

```
Query q = new Query("Product");
List<Entity> entities = datastore.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());

for (Entity entity : entities) {
    entity.setProperty(“sale”, false);
}
datastore.put(entities);
```

Comment: Use a List instead of Iterable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone else can explain to you why exactly it does not work, but I know how to **make** it work.

For some reason the `entities` iterable does not behave like a proper Java collection. In a Java collection, the elements are pointers. But for whatever reason, here each entity that you get inside the for-loop is an independent deep copy. So instead, do the following and it will work

```
    Query q = new Query("Product");
    List<Entity> products = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    for (Entity entity : datastore.prepare(q).asIterable()) {
        entity.setProperty("sale", false);
        products.add(entity);
    }
    datastore.put(products);
```