# .setProperty is not working 100% of the time

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

EDIT: The code has been updated to include the changes suggested by @Igor Artamonov, 
the problem however still occurs! I did noticed the following though with [reference to this image](https://imgur.com/jNIZ9Su), owner 2 had a height value and no tool_proficiency value until owner 3 was added, then 2's height value disappeared and 2's tool value appeared, 2 had smith's tools when it was created 
 End of Edit 
This May be similar to "[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116488/how-to-perform-bulk-update-on-appengine-datastore)" but I couldn't fix the problem using the solutions given there and I couldn't post a comment because I have too little rep :( 
 
 so I hope you don't mind me asking the question I have here :) *note if there is a better place for me to put my question or any problems do tell me, I am very new here :P

I have a java helper for my webpage that sets the properties for an entity in the datastore but every time at least one item is missed if not more? all the items are set using the same function! 
The code on the JSP page:

```
String Username = (String)session.getAttribute("username");
System.out.println("Username carried from session variable = "+Username);

if(request.getParameter("alignment")!=null
&& request.getParameter("Size")!=null 
&& request.getParameter("age")!=null
&& request.getParameter("tools")!=null){

    String HD = "Hill Dwarf";
    String Age = request.getParameter("age");   
    String Alignment = request.getParameter("alignment");   

    int Size = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Size"));
    int Rem = Size%12;
    Size = (Size-(Size%12))/12;
    String Height = (Size+"ft "+Rem+"in");

    String Tools = request.getParameter("tools");   

    System.out.println("setString for hill dwarf: ");
    login.setString(Username, "Race", HD);
    System.out.println("setString for age: ");
    login.setString(Username, "Age", Age);  
    System.out.println("setString for Alignment: ");
    login.setString(Username, "Alignment", Alignment);  
    System.out.println("setString for height: ");
    login.setString(Username, "Height", Height);    
    System.out.println("setString for tools: ");
    login.setString(Username, "Tool_Proficiency", Tools);   
    System.out.println("redirecting to class page");
    response.sendRedirect("class.jsp");
}
```

The code in the login helper:

```
    public void setString(String usernamein,String columnin, String stringin){
    Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction();
    try{
        Filter usernamefilter = new FilterPredicate("owner",
        FilterOperator.EQUAL, usernamein);
        Query validuserquery = new Query("Char").setFilter(usernamefilter);
        Entity theUser = datastore.prepare(validuserquery).asSingleEntity();
        System.out.println("Username passed to setString = "+usernamein);
        System.out.println("Column name passed to setString = "+columnin);
        System.out.println("String passed to setString = "+stringin);
        System.out.println("Query = "+validuserquery);
        if (theUser==null && counter < 30){
            System.out.println("theUser was equal to null");
            try {
                System.out.println("sleeping for 400ms");
                Thread.sleep(400);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            counter ++;
            System.out.println("counter increased, counter = "+counter);
            System.out.println("Recursing function");
            setString(usernamein,columnin,stringin);
        }else{
            System.out.println("theUser was not == null ");
            System.out.println("inputting: "+columnin+" = "+stringin);
            theUser.setProperty(columnin,stringin);
            datastore.put(theUser);
            System.out.println("item added");
        }
        txn.commit();
    }finally{
        if (txn.isActive()){
            txn.rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone needs me to explain the code I will just ask :) 
Okay so this is the code for putting Age, Alignement, etc... into the datastore but it gives this result in the datastore? I don't for the life of me know why!?

****This would have been an image but I need 10 rep for that, so you'll have to [follow this link for the image](https://imgur.com/Wd0KWb1) :( again sorry****

This is what the eclipse console gets from all the System.out.println()'s
this is not code but i'll put it in a code snippet for readability :)

```
HillDwarf page loaded
Username carried from session variable = 12
setString for hill dwarf: 
Username passed to setString = 12
Column name passed to setString = Race
String passed to setString = Hill Dwarf
Query = SELECT * FROM Char WHERE owner = 12
theUSer was not == null 
inputting: Race = Hill Dwarf
item added
setString for age: 
Username passed to setString = 12
Column name passed to setString = Age
String passed to setString = 10
Query = SELECT * FROM Char WHERE owner = 12
theUSer was not == null 
inputting: Age = 10
item added
setString for Alignment: 
Username passed to setString = 12
Column name passed to setString = Alignment
String passed to setString = N
Query = SELECT * FROM Char WHERE owner = 12
theUSer was not == null 
inputting: Alignment = N
item added
setString for height: 
Username passed to setString = 12
Column name passed to setString = Height
String passed to setString = 4ft 5in
Query = SELECT * FROM Char WHERE owner = 12
theUSer was not == null 
inputting: Height = 4ft 5in
item added
setString for tools: 
Username passed to setString = 12
Column name passed to setString = Tool_Proficiency
String passed to setString = Brewer's Supplies
Query = SELECT * FROM Char WHERE owner = 12
theUSer was not == null 
inputting: Tool_Proficiency = Brewer's Supplies
item added
redirecting to class page
```

so My problem as seen in the image, is that the datastore is not getting all the items every time, even though I use the same helper method each time!

please help I have been trying to fix this for days with several approaches :(

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using transaction, so some writes are replaced by others.

Try this:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction();
try {
    /// your current code
    txn.commit();
} finally {
    if (txn.isActive()) {
        txn.rollback();
    }
}
```

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions

PS you also should understand that your current code is 4x times more expensive than code that does same update in one `.put`. I don't see any reason to make it 4 times, for every field separately.

Comment: i'll look into transaction to see if I can understand it. I am aiming to overwrite fields with this method if they have stuff in already with the new value. Cannot think of an alternative to doing it for each field separately as other pages will be using the same method for a different number of attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question as I finally fixed the problem today :S Oh my was it a stupid one too!
In case any one in the future has this problem, make sure you are using keys correctly! 
When Char was created I used this:

```
Key Charkey = KeyFactory.createKey("owner","id");
Entity Char = new Entity("Char", Charkey);
```

In my helper I removed the Transaction (good idea unfortunately it didn't work for me), and 
-Replaced:

```
Filter usernamefilter = new FilterPredicate("owner", FilterOperator.EQUAL, usernamein);
Query validuserquery = new Query("Char").setFilter(usernamefilter);
```

-With:

```
Key Charkey = KeyFactory.createKey("owner","id");
Filter usernamefilter = new FilterPredicate("owner", FilterOperator.EQUAL, usernamein);
Query validuserquery = new Query("Char",Charkey).setFilter(usernamefilter);
```

pretty silly mistake that cost me hours! I am so new to datastore though so I kinda expect these mistakes anyway hopefully this fixes someone elses problem at some point in the future :D